# How to release an update for AppJs desktop app?

Tags: javascript, appjs

Is there a way to auto update the node.js script and the html files?

Answer (score 0):

Also there is no updating feature inside AppJS, it is easy to program a script for your own app to update html/js files. The procedure is as follows:
1. Manage your folders so html/js files are placed inside a versioned folder say `app-v1.0` and create a symlink name it `current` folder that refers to `app-v1.0`.
2. Write a nodejs script which checks for updates by calling a web service. If any new update is available, it should download it and place it in another versioned folder say `app-v2.0`, update `current` folder symlink to refer to this new update.
3. In `app.js` where your program starts, call the above script wait for it to finish and open your window.